# Handle ProcessCmdKey Between Two UserControls

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have two UserControls as below:

1. CashDeposit
2. GeneralAccount

GeneralAccount  UserControl added into cashdeposit  UserControl and it set as invisible on **Form Load.** GeneralAccount will visible by pressing **Ctrl + C** from Datagridview texbox column  KeyUp Event.

I am confused on handle **ProcessCmdKey EventHandller** between these two controls.
My task is on press of Escape Key the visible control should be invisible. If Generalaccount visible on CashDeposit than Generalaccount should be invisible only on press of Escape Key not CashDeposit too. And if GeneralAccount not visible and user press Escape Key than CashDeposit Usercontrols should be invisible.
I am trying this as follow but fails.

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Escape) 
        {
            if (genac.Visible==true )// Checking GeneralAccount Visible or Not
            {
                genac.Visible = false;
                dgv.Focus();
            }
            else 
            {
                //Referenced Delegate to the Event for Closing or set visible true or  false 
                //for CashDeposit UserControls From WinForm Application.
                cashdepositkeydownevent cdkd = CashDepositKeyDownEvent;
                if (cdkd != null)
                    cdkd(ref msg, keyData);

            }

        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);

    }
```

The above is works well if the GeneralControls Visible and press Escape Key. if it is not visible as set it visible=false on formLoad Eventhandller and if I press Escape than it Throw Error Like

> “Null Reference Exception was UnHandled., Object reference Not set”

. At

```
if (genac.Visible==true )// Checking GeneralAccount Visible or Not
```

How to Solve it?.

Comment: Are you sure your `genac` is not reference to the `null` ?

Comment: @SonerGönül, Yes it is Null on Load. It is added on Datagridview textbox keyUp Column.

Comment: @Manesh If it is a `null`, you can't get its property. That's why you are getting null reference exception. Add it on the top.

Comment: @SonerGönül, You are right but I don't want to add GeneralAccount to my Cashdeposit account for improve performance of application memory. I just want it at temporary basis and then after it will be remove and dispose it on press of escape key. So in such case how to do it?.

Comment: ... there are many temeporary basis UserControl which I have to add in such CashDeposit Account.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can't do like that.

Comment: @SonerGönül, Ok than there any better solution for such problem?.

Comment: ... because I am not in favor to add temporary controls on main controls and engaged the memory.